# Java - Delete file after reading from it

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out why my inputFile.delete() will not delete the file. After looking at numerous topics it looks like something is still using the file and hence it won't delete. But I can't figure it out. What am I missing??

```
File inputFile = new File("data/Accounts.txt");
File tempFile = new File("data/tmp.txt");

try {
    tempFile.createNewFile();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    String line;

    int i = 0;
    for (User u : data) {
        String toRemove = getIDByUsername(username);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(toRemove + " ")) {
                line = (i + " " + username + " " + getStatusByUsername(username) + " " + password);
            }
            writer.write(line + "\n");
            i++;
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    ex.FileNotFound();
} catch (IOException ee) {
    ex.IOException();
} finally {
    inputFile.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: @OldProgrammer no, it builds successfully

Comment: Your exception handling pattern makes no sense. You are catching FileNotFound exception, but deleting and renaming files in "finally" block, even though the error may have happened. Try to fix this logic, make sure you manipulate files only when previous operations succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

You can have that much shorter and easier by using `java.nio`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide the path to your file, (might have to be an absolute path!)
    Path filePath = Paths.get("data/Accounts.txt");

    // lines go here, initialize it as empty list
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // read all lines (alternatively, you can stream them by Files.lines(...)
        lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
        // do your logic here, this is just a very simple output of the content
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", lines));
        // delete the file
        Files.delete(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        // handle the situation of a non existing file (wrong path or similar)
        System.err.println("The file at " + filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                + " could not be found." + System.lineSeparator()
                + fnfe.toString());
    } catch (FileSystemException fse) {
        // handle the situation of an inaccessible file
        System.err.println("The file at " + filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                + " could not be accessed:" + System.lineSeparator()
                + fse.toString());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // catch unexpected IOExceptions that might be thrown
        System.err.println("An unexpected IOException was thrown:" + System.lineSeparator()
                + ioe.toString());
    }
}
```

This prints the content of the file and deletes it afterwards.
You will want to do something different instead of just printing the content, but that will be possible, too ;-) Try it...

Comment: One minor nit: This kind of exceptionhandling is training java newbies in very bad habits. The proper way to deal with exceptions here is clearly to tag your main method with 'throws Exception' - it's allowed, it's shorter, it leads to as much or more information, and it doesn't create the nasty scenario where a failure causes a bunch of text to be echoed whilst code continues to run (likely throwing off more errors, drowning the screen in endless stack traces, and only the very first one was probably useful).

Comment: I suppose you should use a`Stream` so you can filter out the lines as the OP code does.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'd agree if it were catching `Exception `, don't see much wrong with catching the `IOException` though (with better handling than printing it though obviously).

Comment: @daniu You can declare main to 'throws IOException' too if you like.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I just improved the exception handling (a bit)... Hope this won't be frowned upon anymore. Sure, the `main` could just `throws IOException` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to figure out why my inputFile.delete() will not delete the file.

That's because the old file API is crappy specifically in this way: It has no ability to tell you why something is not succeeding. All it can do, is return 'false', which it will.

See the other answer, by @deHaar which shows how to do this with the newer API. Aside from being cleaner code and the newer API giving you more options, the newer API also fixes this problem where various methods, such as `File.delete()`, cannot tell you the reason for why it cannot do what you ask.

There are many, many issues with your code, which is why I strongly suggest you go with deHaar's attempt. To wit:

1. You aren't properly closing your resources; if an exception happens, your file handlers will remain open.
2. Both reading and writing here is done with 'platform default encoding', whatever that might be. Basically, never use those `FileReader` and `FileWriter` constructors. Fortunately, the new API defaults to UTF_8 if you fail to specify an encoding, which is more sensible.
3. your exception handling is not great (you're throwing away any useful messages, whatever ex.FileNotFound() might be doing here) - and you still try to delete-and-replace even if exceptions occur, which then fail, as your file handles are still open.
4. The method should be called getIdByUsername
5. Your toRemove string is the same every time, or at least, the `username` variable does not appear to be updated as you loop through. If indeed it never updates, move that line out of your loop.